# Google app scripts How do I move several files into a folder?

Tags: javascript, file, google-apps-script

Anyone can help me? I need move several files. so What i do is find the files by name. but When i use getfilebyName  the type is file interator, i cant make copy on that. 
the code following is worked but I dun know how to do on several files

```
function copyAndMove(files,folder){

  var files = DriveApp.getFileById('16QnYGb19tlCDu18KNwYPZkNgtE4T2ElK3Q_djI-hF64');
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('0B6ZorjJGEpzgOFFQdF9yT24zc2s');
 var newfile = files.makeCopy('copy of '+ files.getName(), folder);
    DriveApp.removeFile(files);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your Iterator by using the statement below:

```
while (files.hasNext()) {

        var file = files.next();
        // do stuff with the file

}
```

For example, this code allow you to move the content from one folder to another one:

```
function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder) {

  var files = source_folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    dest_folder.addFile(file);
    source_folder.removeFile(file);

  }
}
```

Source : [ctrlq.org](https://ctrlq.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders)

**Edit:** You can move file by names. This function will get file by name, remove them from their actual location and put them on the dest_folder:

```
function moveFiles(string_name, dest_folder) {

  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string_name);

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    var parents = file.getParents();

    while (parents.hasNext()) {

      var parent = parents.next();
      parent.removeFile(file);

    }

    dest_folder.addFile(file);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but That will move all files in my old folder, can i move files by name ????

Comment: If this answer is working for you, don't forget to mark this answer as approuved. So other people with the same question can find more easily a appropriate answer.

Comment: sorry reply late it is work on moving files but not whatever i type it move all files in new folder, can u help me figure what is going on?